# How do I save the output of last executed command in terminal after normally executing a command?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have an incremental build command for my project that will output something if I do a clean build, and output something else (less) if I do an incremental build.

Say, I forgot to do this:

```
mycommand.sh > myfile.txt
```

or this

```
mycommand.sh >> myfile.txt
```

for saving the output to a file.

How can I save this if I already run a clean build `mycommand.sh` and the output is printed on terminal window (without using copy paste)?

Comment: you can do something like that with [kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/), havnt tested it myself

Comment: To be clear, this question is absolutely on topic here. Such questions are very welcome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `$(!!)` to view the output of the last executed command.

```
my_command
echo $(!!)
```

Example:

```
ls $HOME
echo $(!!)
```

Comment: it would be good to explain that this *runs* the last command again, which will not always give the same result, rather than magically retrieving the output. One may as well just hit the up arrow and append `> file`...